# WS2812 vs TLC5947

Tags: led, stm32, led-driver

I want to know why one would use the TLC5947 constant current driver over a WS2812.

What are the benefits of the TLC5947?
Do you have more control since you can set the max current of an LED?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a TLC5947 with *any* LED, giving you freedom to use whatever LEDs suit your needs.

The WS2812 are modules with the LED built in, along with some type of controller very like the TLC5947, so you're stuck with whatever colour spectrum that particular LED has, which is far from flat.

If I wanted to control current through a bunch of flat-spectrum white LEDs, or LEDs of a particular wavelength (I don't need RGB), I would use the TLC5947 or similar.

Comment: What about if i wanted to run RGB leds with a TLC5947, would this be silly?